# Good way to start developing for iPhone, given some experience in Cocoa on Mac

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos

I have some experience of Objective-C/Cocoa programming on Mac and
I'd like to start developing for iPhone/iPad with UIKit. (I just paid $99 to the mother ship.)
What would be a nice way to start? I'd like to have your suggestions/recommendations. More specifically,

- Which book I should buy? Is there a nice book contrasting AppKit/UIKit differences?
- What are the most common pitfalls in UIKit for an AppKit programmer?

Please note I'm *not* asking what would be the best for a total newcomer to the Objective-C/Cocoa world. Maybe I should start humbly and start from scratch, but the general question of how to  start programming for iPhone 
 would be a duplicate here in SO :p

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would get [Beginning iPhone Development by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430224594).  It might be a little slow for you, but you could always skim through it.

Comment: Went to a bookstore and had a look at it. I'm now debating whether I should get this one or Sadun's...

Comment: I haven't gotten a good chance to look at Sadun's.  I wonder if it's on Safari Books...

Answer (score 3):

The CS193P course on iTunesU gives you a good overview ([iTunes Link](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225)). The first couple may be a bit slow for you if you have come Cocoa & Objective-C but the rest should get you up and running.

Comment: Thanks, I skimmed through the pdfs... UIKit is indeed different from AppKit, but in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend any of the following

- iPhone Developer Cookbook - Erica Sadun,
- iPhone SDK Programming - Bill Dudney
- iPhone Advanced Projects - (Assorted authors), published by Apress

Answer (score 0):

The most common pitfall is to expect the iPhone to be able to do anything a regular computer can.

It can't. There are a lot of innocent, reasonable tasks that are rendered impossible by sandboxing, API design choices and the review process. In other words, the answer to "Can I do X on the iPhone?" is often  "No". Do your research before embarking on an ambitious project.